# 3D manipulator widget in multi-selection does not appear

Tags: modeling

I can see my 3D manipulator tool all right, but I cannot see it when I select everything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: perhaps you have an object out of sight, or perhaps the origin of one object is far from its mesh?

Comment: Thanks moonboots, but how can I check if there is an object far from its mesh? For I zoomed out and there is no object out of sight. I can always see the Scale Manipulator, though, but not the rotate tool either.

Comment: please share your file (if it's ok for you) so that we can see the problem: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5145" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5145/)

Comment: Hi MoonBoots. I went on deleting objects and trying to select and see the Widget. In the end I realized I can't see the Manipulator if I have this window in the scene. It is an AddOn. Do you know what I have to do, please?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> in your 3D view, the *3D view properties* panel will display on the right, you can see that some of your objects *Transform* parameters are locked, you can't see any manipulator if at least one of the objects you select has these transformators locked.

[image]

Those parameters are also available in the *Properties* panel > *Objects* > *Transform Locks*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, MoonBoots! Thank you! Four months with Blender makes me wonder why we like to suffer.

Comment: one day you'll see the end of the tunnel, and paradise